# JEE - reset ejb singleton everyday

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, runtime

I'm using JEE and I created EJB-Singleton. It has as a field LRUMap, which represents cache to store data in application. I want to clear that data inside singleton or just kill and start again whole singleton during runtime. 
Is there any option to do that periodically? For example to reset singleton bean once per day in order to clear data?

Here is the code:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class BpNotificationCacheBean {

    private static final int CACHE_SIZE = 1000;

    private Map<String, Boolean> cacheMap;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cacheMap = new LRUMap(CACHE_SIZE);
    }

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public Boolean get(String businessPartnerId) {
        return cacheMap.get(businessPartnerId);
    }

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void put(String businessPartnerId, Boolean isVIP) {
        this.cacheMap.put(businessPartnerId, isVIP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a full JEE environment, I'd create a `Schedule` annotated method:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;

@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class BpNotificationCacheBean {

    private static final int CACHE_SIZE = 1000;

    private Map<String, Boolean> cacheMap;

    ...

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    @Schedule(hour = "1", persistent = false)
    private void resetCache() {
        cacheMap = new LRUMap(CACHE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

The key is the Schedule annotation which is part of the [Java EE Timer Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).  The annotation I show runs a 01:00 (1AM) every day but see the docs to show how to change that.

Comment: No problem @RafałDwórznik - if this is the correct answer I'd appreciate you marking it as the accepted answer.